# How to get data from custom UID in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

I have data structure like this for my android app. That can login and only see their profile. I dont make add content or do saving data to the database. So i created the data manually and the users only read and display the data.

How to make login,refer with username = "71140011" and password = "123456" which is inside real time database and the 71140011 only can see their profile only. thanks

Comment: Try to use Custom Authentication System https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth